# Pivot Table VBA - add multiple 'sum of' data fields and clear existing pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I’m having some trouble doing vba code for a pivot table (first time doing a pivot in vba). The rest of the code works, but there are two additional things that I just can’t work out.

Firstly, if the macro has already been run and then there are changes to the data, I would like the pivot table to update/refresh (or delete existing and paste new version over existing) – currently the code only works if there is no pivot table in A54.

Secondly, I would like to add an additional 3 ‘sum of’ value fields, but I can only seem to get one to work. Current code is:

```
Sub PivotTable()

    Dim objWS As Worksheet
    Dim objPT As PivotTable
    Dim objPC As PivotCache

    'Note I have already created a table of the data set and named it
    "tblTimesht"
    Set objWS = ActiveSheet

    Set objPC = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "tblTimesht")

    Set objPT = objPC.CreatePivotTable(objWS.Range("A54"), TableName:="Time
    Pivot")

    With objPT
        With .PivotFields("Job Code")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With

        With .PivotFields("Budget Line")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 2
        End With

        .AddDataField .PivotFields("Hours"), "Sum of Hours", xlSum
    End With
```

These are the additional datafields I have tried to add unsuccessfully after the last line of code above:

```
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("Overtime 1.5x"), "Sum of Overtime 1.5x", xlSum
    End With

        .AddDataField .PivotFields("Overtime 2x"), "Sum of Overtime 2x", xlSum
    End With

        .AddDataField .PivotFields("Overtime 2.5x"), "Sum of Overtime 2.5x", xlSum
    End With
```

Thank you!

Comment: why you have `End With` at the end of every statement ? You need to add these line after the previous `.AddDataField .PivotFields("Hours"), "Sum of Hours", xlSum` and before the `End With`

Comment: Thank you Shai Rado, that works now! Do you know how I can update the code to remove existing pivot table and re-paste new each time the macro is run (and the datas has been updated) too?